# How to make scatter plot log scale (with label in original scale) in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

How to make some plot like this in matplotlib, for make it simple, I was trying `(np.log10(df['amount'].dropna().values))` but the x lable is in log scale (not original scale), I want something like David Robinson plot, here's my

```
label   price    growth
A       90       10%
B       32       32%
C       3        22%
D       0.3      16%
E       1        10%
```

What I want is something like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use seaborn to do this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
```

data:

```
label   price   growth
0   A   90.0    0.10
1   B   32.0    0.32
2   C   3.0     0.22
3   D   0.3     0.16
4   E   1.0     0.10
```

Plot:

```
ax = sns.lmplot('price', # Horizontal axis
           'growth', # Vertical axis
           data=data, # Data source
           fit_reg=False, # Don't fix a regression line
           size = 5,
           aspect =1 ) # size and dimension

plt.title('Example Plot')
# Set x-axis label
plt.xlabel('price')
plt.xscale('log')
# Set y-axis label
plt.ylabel('growth')


def label_point(x, y, val, ax):
    a = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y, 'val': val}, axis=1)
    for i, point in a.iterrows():
        ax.text(point['x']+.02, point['y'], str(point['val']))

label_point(data.price, data.growth, data.label, plt.gca())
```

[image]

Comment: What I want is price is on log scale, and why your font in very small

Comment: I asumming `plt.scatter()` solution

Comment: just change the size and aspect of the plot

Comment: Nice, but I still assuming log scale for best answer

Comment: Just add this plt.xscale('log')

Comment: this one is 'the standard form of numbers' not decimal